# Python Django, How I Can use username(uname) or email as a login credentials?

Tags: python, django, django-views

Python Django, How  I Can use username(uname) or email as a login credentials ?
my python file are views,URLs,models,settings.py

def loginpage(request):

```
if request.method=="POST":
    try:
        Userdetails=newacc.objects.get(email=request.POST['email'],pwd=request.POST['pwd'])
        print("Username=",Userdetails)
        request.session[ 'email']=Userdetails.email
        return render(request,'Logout.html')
    except newacc.DoseNotExist as e:
        messages.success(request,' Username / Password Invalid.')
return render(request,'Login.html')
```

Comment: Python Django, How I Can use either username(uname) or email as a login credentials ? my python file are views,URLs,models,settings.py

Comment: Please read the documentation on [Using the Django authentication system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/), your implementation of authentication is very bad and probably insecure (If the session were to be cookie based anyone would basically be able to impersonate other users)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with a `Q` object to make a disjunction between `email` and `uname`:

```
from django.db.models import Q

if request.method=="POST":
    try:
        Userdetails=newacc.objects.get(
            Q(email=request.POST['email']) | Q(uname=request.POST['email']),
            pwd=request.POST['pwd']
        )
        print("Username=",Userdetails)
        request.session[ 'email']=Userdetails.email
        return render(request,'Logout.html')
    except newacc.DoseNotExist as e:
        messages.success(request,' Username / Password Invalid.')
return render(request,'Login.html')
```

But it seems that your user model does *not* make use of *password hashing*. I strongly advise to [read the documentation on *password management*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/passwords/#password-management-in-django) and hash passwords in your user model to prevent hackers from exploiting the passwords stored in the database if they manage to read that. See also [this section on *Customizing Authentication in Django*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/).